# Who is behind which ID in Audit logs

Tags: auditing, logs

I recently activated `Audit Logs` on my SharePoint Server.

I use Audit Logging for security reasons. I want to know which user changed rights or groups.

I tried this by deleting someone from a group. As result I get following event:

```
<groupid>7</groupid><user>14</user>
```

Can I somehow see who is behind `UserID 14` and which group is behind `GroupID 17`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For looking up both group and user you might use this url:

```
<siteurl>/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?id=<userid_or_groupid>
```

It shows you either the user's information or the group's members depending on the entered id represents a group or a user.

**Caution:** The ids are unique within site collections only. So `...?id=42` within `site collection A` might be a different user or group in `site collection B`.

Comment: I guess this only works in SharePoint 2013?